# how to make listview and button appear in landscape mode

Tags: android, json, android-layout, listview

I wanted to know why the Listview and button disappear in landscape mode.
I have written a simple code to parse Json from server when i click the "get data" button and display the Json string in a Listview.

My activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.demoapp.mrrobot.volleyexample.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGet"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="461dp"
        android:text="Get Data"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="349dp"
        android:layout_height="436dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.514"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My list_view_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewId"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewName"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
   // android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: why you ignoring MissingConstraints you are using ConstraintLayout then you have to apply minimal constraint to work layout on all device and on any orientation also post the described problem what you want to achieve and the problem you getting

Comment: @Pavan i have taken taken help of this guide."https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/" and created the app as specified and it works but when i try to vieew the app in landscape , textview and button disappear.

Comment: yes, i want button at top and listview below button

Comment: no it doesnt work...and now json string also doesnt show up in listview

Answer (score -1):

You should create a different .xml file for the landscape mode and put it in the folder layout-land